# Php com Firebird

Tags: php

É possível o php fazer conexão com banco de dados Firebird?

Estou com uma demanda de criar um sistema em php que tenha conexão. Para gerar dados e ser enviado isso por email

Comment: Com PDO: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-firebird.php

Comment: Obrigado amigo !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema com a biblioteca Ibase do php